# Spring cloud gateway passing user object down to the microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, architecture, microservices, api-gateway

Dears,
I am looking for the best practices on how to pass down user object to the microservices from API gateway. user object has many roles and it is pretty big, that's why I don't want to use HTTP headers. I can save the user in Redis by setting a unique id for the key and sending this unique key with a header, then in the custom filter (in microservice) I can get and set it to the security context, but I am not sure if is it the right way. I need your suggestions.

Comment: how can you decide which request belong to which user if you save user in redis? you can use token to pass user login info, and use a login microservices to decode the token and get user id, and query user detail from user microservices, from which you have cache user info in redis

Comment: I can generate some unique id and send it with an HTTP header to microservice and in microservice, with that id, I can get user info from Redis. with this approach, there will be only one HTTP request to the authorization server.

Comment: when request come, your generate one more uniqueId and put one more user object into redis? it will take up a lot of memory.